# Svg as a background without css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a big svg file (with animation and stuff), and I want to use it as a background for my site.
At my site I have  so when I shrink the page, svg adapts fully by orientating on window width, so my

starts to go out of background and create white background for itself.
I can solve it with CSS

```
background: url(background.svg)
```

but svg then starts lagging pretty hard, so I wonder if I can make my background svg more adaptive on height, and do it in more html/svg way

Note: Im doing it with react, and I put svg in index.html from react-app,  is goes far away from my svg size.

It sounds confusing, but I think Im not the only one who struggled with it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: please, show your code so I can help, but i think you will need css in this point

Comment: Using SVG as css background may be tricky. You may want to read this article first: [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris). If after reading this article you still have problems please add the svg to your question and I will try to help.